# Sharing values between queries (and subqueries)

Tags: sql, teradata

I am trying to create a query which requires a join on a sub-query. However I also need to be able to limit the sub-queries' results by the results from my main query.

I have modified my previous question to show the full 'conceptual' query which I would like to run. I am aware that it will be fraught with issues however I lack the experience (currently) to be able to modify the syntax enough to make this query run.

Example below:

```
    SELECT
    w.timestamp,
    c.timestamp
FROM
    table1 w
FULL OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT
            customer_id,
            timestamp
        FROM
            table1 c
        HAVING
            c.timestamp < w.timestamp
        AND
            timestamp = MAX(c.timestamp)) c
ON
    w.customer_id = c.customer_id
WHERE
    payment_type_code='WithdrawPayment'
AND
    w.customer_id IN
        (SELECT
            customer_id,
            timestamp
        FROM
            table1
        WHERE
            c.timestamp < w.timestamp
        AND
            timestamp = MAX(c.timestamp)
    ORDER BY
            c.timestamp DESC
        )
HAVING
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
         table1 u
    WHERE
        u.timestamp > c.timestamp
    AND
        u.timestamp < w.timestamp) u > 0
;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Scoping rules. Just move the "c.timestamp < w.timestamp" condition to the JOIN's ON clause. BTW, WHERE condition automatically transforms OUTER JOIN to INNER JOIN for the action_type column's table.

Comment: So I could write: SELECT
    w.timestamp,
    c.timestamp
FROM
    table1 w
FULL OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT
        customer_id,
        timestamp
    FROM
        table1 c
    HAVING
        timestamp = MAX(c.timestamp)) c
ON
    w.customer_id < c.customer_id
WHERE
    action_type ='type1'
;

Comment: Not sure that will work for me as I am trying to join on the customer_id but only when c.timestamp < w.timestamp. Unless I am able to add that in addition to the w.customer_id = c.customer_id. Are you able to provide an example?

Comment: Your example has several flaws. You select two fields from c without any GROUP BY clause, but use HAVING. Then in HAVING you try to access both aggregated and non-aggregated fields. And then, yes, you are even trying to access fields of w in your derived table query. Is there a reason you cannot move the w access to the ON clause?

Comment: I have modified my query to replace the 'HAVING' keyword with the 'WHERE' keyword and am (in theory) limiting the results to just the one by returning the 'MAX' timestamp. Can you explain the difference between 'aggregated' and 'non-aggregated' fields as everything I have looked at seems to make me more confused and finally, how do I move the 'w access to the ON clause'?

Comment: I have posted some kind of an answer. (There is no real answer, as we don't know what your query is supposed to do and there are way too many flaws in it.) I hope it helps you along. When you are replying to someone, you should address him/her like so: @Nic2352. Otherwise the other gets no notification of your reply (except for when you are replying in the comments section of their answer).

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned in the comments, your query is totally flawed: You can't access both aggregated and detail data at the same time and you can't correlate with a query in a Derived Table.

But you seem to look for the maximum timestamp in table2 before the one in table1 and this can be expressed like this:

```
SELECT
    w.timestamp,
    c.timestamp
FROM
    table1 w
LEFT JOIN
    table1 c
ON
    w.customer_id = c.customer_id -- join on customer_id
AND c.timestamp < w.timestamp     -- using only earlier timestamps
WHERE
    action_type ='type1'
QUALIYF
    RANK()
    OVER (PARTITION BY w.customer_id -- assuming there's only one row per customer in w
          ORDER BY c.timestamp DESC) = 1 -- find the maximum timestamp
```

Comment: I have modified my query in the question above. I am aware that it will still be fraught with issues but as I mentioned above I don't have the experience or understanding to be able to modify it sufficiently

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. You better  explain your rules in detail and add DDL and sample data. Is `table1` actually always the same table?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not valid SQL and it is not even clear what you are trying to achieve with it. (I must admit I even fail to guess your query's purpose.) You should tell us what the query is supposed to do rather than asking us to point out your syntax errors.

Anyhow, let's start with your derived table:

```
SELECT customer_id, timestamp
FROM table1 c
HAVING c.timestamp < w.timestamp
AND timestamp = MAX(c.timestamp)
```

You are selecting table1 records (limited to the columns customer_id and timestamp to be precise). You are selecting all rows (no WHERE clause). Then there is a HAVING clause. This is invalid here. A HAVING clause works after aggregating values, e.g. if you had selected MIN(customer_id) and MAX(timestamp) either as one record or per group (with GROUP BY). As is, your HAVING clause makes no sense, and I actually wonder how you got the idea to use it at all.

Then within the HAVING clause you compare timestamp with MAX(timestamp). You cannot do that. There is a time before aggregation, when you can look at a record and its timestamp column for instance. Then there is a time after aggregation, when you can look at MAX(timestamp). You don't see them at the same time. In order to do so, you would have to select from the same table twice, once to look at single records, once to look at the aggregation. As in:

```
SELECT customer_id, timestamp
FROM table1 c
WHERE timestamp = (select MAX(timestamp) from table1)
```

Here I check for every record, whether its timestamp equals the maximum timestamp for the table and keep only those records.

Moreover you are accessing w.timestamp which is not visible here. You could only compare the timestamp outside the derived table query:

```
FROM table1 w
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT customer_id, timestamp
  FROM table1
  WHERE timestamp = (select MAX(timestamp) from table1)
) c ON c.timestamp = w.timestamp
```

At last you are doing a full outer join. Why? `X FULL OUTER JOIN Y` keeps X records that are not available in Y and vice versa. You, however, select `FROM table1 w`, so you get all records from table1 and join with a subset of table1 (your derived table query). So there cannot be records from the derived table that have no match in table1. Hence a *full* outer join makes no sense at all. Then in your query's WHERE clause you ask for certain w.customer_id. If the outer join *would* work, you would get made up records where w.customer_id is null. Your WHERE clause would remove these. Another reason why your full outer join makes no sense.

What more? Well you are asking `w.customer_id IN (SELECT customer_id, timestamp FROM ...)`. This is syntactically wrong. The single value `w.customer_id` can never match a value pair `customer_id, timestamp`. You could ask `w.customer_id IN (SELECT customer_id FROM ...)` instead.

Then again in your main query you are using HAVING although there is no aggregation done.

I think it would be good if you practised with very basic queries. A query with WHERE. A query with an aggregation, say MAX. A query with an aggregation per group (i.e. using GROUP BY). A query with an aggregation and a HAVING clause. A query with a WHERE clause *and* a HAVING clause...

As to your query here: Maybe what I have said above helps you build it step by step. If not, come back and tell us what your query is supposed to do and we'll show you how.